# Executing an Init Script Using Testcontainers Postgres for Scala

Tags: postgresql, scala, testcontainers

I'm trying to use the `testcontainers-scala-postgresql` to spin up some tests using Testcontainers, PostgreSQL and Scala. I want to run an init script during container startup to create and populate the table.

However, the `com.dimafeng.testcontainers.PostgreSQLContainer` type doesn't contain the `withInitScript` method, which is present in the Java version.

Is there any other way I can configure the execution of an init script during startup?

Comment: Using the Java testcontainers is probably your best option. There's not really a need for a Scala API to use testcontainers IMHO.

Comment: Like Gael says you can use the Java test containers or run the init script in afterContainersStart() method.

Comment: I'm using the Scala API because it integrates smoothly with ScalaTest :). Can you share some examples?

Answer (score 1):

You could use PostgreSQLContainer.Def, where are an ability to pass commonJdbcParams with initScriptPath:

```
  val initScriptParam = JdbcDatabaseContainer.CommonParams(initScriptPath = Option("init_script.sql"))
  val postgresqlContainer: PostgreSQLContainer = PostgreSQLContainer.Def(commonJdbcParams = initScriptParam).createContainer()
```

Answer (score 0):

Postgres image has the option to init the database on start, here's the docs on [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) (look for the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`).

In short, `*.sql`, `*.sql.gz`, or `*.sh` scripts under `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` are executed on startup.

In the Java version you can use the `withCopyFileToContainer` method, I think something similar should be in Scala right?

So something like:

```
new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:14-alpine")
  .withCopyFileToContainer(
              MountableFile.forClasspathResource("/schema.sql"),
              "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/"
  );
```

And if you have more files, they will be executed in lexicographic order.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Oleg. I know how to do it in Java...I asked for a Scala solution :)

Comment: there's no `withCopyFileToContainer`? that's unfortunate, can you create an issue, it's such an important API